# AngularUI datepicker allows typing value outside of range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm having an issue where I'm using AngularUI to specify a datepicker with some allowed range of input values. For example, the user can select a date from 2013-06-10 to 2013-06-20. This works fine as long as the user is clicking inside the datepicker, but it does not work correctly when the user types a date outside of the range. In that case it will update the model to the typed value but revert back to the range in the ui.

Here's a plnkr that demonstrates the issue: http://plnkr.co/kmU8vM6OGNsus0Upp02g. Try typing a value that is outside of the allowed range.

Has anybody else experienced this problem? Is there a bugfix or workaround?

Comment: It works for me. I typed in 2013-05-15 and it updated the model to the first date of the date range: Mon Jun 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1000

Comment: Yes you are allowed to type but when the actual blur event happens the value is checked and if it's lower than the min it will put in the min value. Same goes for max values

Comment: Really? It doesn't work for me in FF 21.0 or Chrome 27 or Chrome 29 (Canary). Maybe you pressed 'Enter' after typing a value? Try 'Tab' or clicking outside the input field.

Comment: @DanielLidström: tab/enter/click outside every time the value that I entered that was incorrect would be corrected to the min/max value. I'm using Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m

Comment: Ok Liviu, thanks for letting me know. I guess it might depend on some user-specific settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved with the new plugin version: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date. So solution is to stop using "bundled" angular-ui and instead start using the plugin versions instead.

Comment: Is't the whole point of the angular-ui project to use best practices for angularjs. This would mean not using jQuery.