# AngularUI Datepicker Allows Typing Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, datepicker

I am having a problem where in the AngularUI Bootstrap Datepicker I have a min date and a max date. It is working where if you open the popup, you can't click on the disabled dates. However you CAN type in a date outside of the range. I want it to bring it to the min date if the typed date is below and the max date if the typed date is later.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6U4YdTIyFXjOqRJm2qTq?p=preview

In the controller:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    maxDate: $scope.maxDate,
    minDate: $scope.minDate,
};
```

In the template: `datepicker-options="dateOptions"`

I don't seem to be the first to run into this issue, since there are defect reports, however they are reporting as "fixed" and yet this is still happening. I'd like to avoid using jQuery or a date library unless necessary, since this is the only field where I need this functionality.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2901

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/3020

The similar stackflow question

[AngularUI datepicker allows typing value outside of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184840/angularui-datepicker-allows-typing-value-outside-of-range) actually has a working plunker but it isn't angularui datepicker, and the accepted answer suggests a plug-in, which I want to avoid. I did try using `ui-date="dateOptions"` in my template the same as the plunker but nothing changed.